# SocketException while trying SaveChanges on a list of blobs with Entity Framework and MariaDB using Pomelo NUGET package

Tags: entity-framework, mariadb, socketexception, savechanges, pomelo-entityframeworkcore-mysql

I would like to switch from SQLExpress to MariaDB, but run into an issue with SaveChanges.

I can replicate the exception related to the byte[] with a console test application easily using this code, which runs perfectly if I try the same on SQLExpress.

**What puzzles me is:**

**TestScenario 1:** Put the byte[] into TestTable class, it works with MariaDB.

**TestScenario 2:** Replace the list of SubTable with just one instance of subtable. -> Works

**TestScenario 3:** Replace the byte[] in SubTable by e.g. a single int -> again works

Each time I used add-migration and update-database prior to running the code.

**The error message I am getting is:** 
"SocketException: Eine bestehende Verbindung wurde softwaregesteuert
durch den Hostcomputer abgebrochen."
"SocketException: Failed to read the result set."

I am using the latest version from Pomelo as well as EFCore via NUGET manager.

Honestly I am at a loss. The only information I could find on google was to check the maximum package size setting, but this is well above the blob size for my DB.

**So here is my code:**

A simple TestTable class with a List of SubTables.

```
public class TestTable
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public List<SubTable> sub { get; set; } = new List<SubTable>();
    }


    public class SubTable
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }

        public int ParentID { get; set; }
        public SubTable Parent { get; set; } //<- see Update Mai, 19th, 2020 below


        public byte[] blob { get; set; } //<- here is the root cause for the issue (see Update Mai, 19th, 2020)
    }
```

SubTable contains the blob as an array of bytes.

The ModelContext is derived from DBContext so nothing fancy here. Just the connection string, which needs to be adapted to the specific system.

```
    public partial class ModelContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<TestTable> TestData { get; set; }
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {

            optionsBuilder.UseMySql(@"Server=<IP>;Database=<DB>;User Id=<ID>;Password=<PW>;");
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        }
    }
```

In the main part of the console app, I create the ModelContext and initialize my datastructure. I am using Code-First approach, having the database created by using add-migration and update-database.

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var db = new ModelContext())
            {
                TestTable t = new TestTable();

                for (int index = 0; index < 4000; index++)
                    t.sub.Add(new SubTable() { blob = new byte[5000] });

                db.TestData.Add(t);
                db.SaveChanges(); // <- at this point the exception is raised
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Done!");
        }
    }
}
```

This is how the migration part of subtable looks like:

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "SubTable",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    ID = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("MySql:ValueGenerationStrategy", MySqlValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn),
                    ParentID = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
                    blob = table.Column<byte[]>(nullable: true),
                    TestTableID = table.Column<int>(nullable: true)
                },
```

So basically this is a standard scenario which can be found on numerous web sites and blogs, if there would not be the exception, which I do not understand.

Any help/suggestions apprechiated.

**UPDATE 2020 Mai 19:**
Out of curiosity, I again tried to solve the issue. So I installed the newest version of MariaDB.

1. I received an error message indicating something is wrong with the
   foreign key design.
2. Double checking the foreign key, I found a bug
   in my code. `public SubTable Parent { get; set; }` should be:
   `public TestTable Parent { get; set; }`

--> Now it works just fine with the newest version of MariaDB.

The MariaDB version (V5.5.xx) running on my NAS won't though. Sad but definetly not a show stopper.

So for me the issue is closed, as it seems to be related to an outdated version of MariaDB.

Cheers,
Axel

Comment: Update - Out of curiosity I tried again with some different scenarios:

Comment: Pomelo is officially only compatible with the latest two versions of MariaDB (though MariaDB 10.2.x should work fine for most scenarios as well). So this might just be either an incompatibility between Pomelo and MariaDB 5.5 or between MySqlConnector and MariaDB 5.5.